# Добавление или удаление компонентов

Tags: qt, qt5

Решил В свой Qt 5.10.1 добавить ещё один компилятор запустил MaintenanceTool.exe из папки в которой Qt лежит.

Я сам не зарегистрирован в qt корпорации.

В общем нажимал далее, далее.

Вывел мне надпись красным цветом "Для выполнения требуется хотя бы одно действующее хранилище".

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Прочёл здесь](http://www.prog.org.ru/index.php?topic=31118.0) как репозиторий подключить.
Но почему-то пишет ошибку "Не удалось открыть файл Updates.xml для чтения: No file name specified"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Как провести добавление компонента ?

Обязательна ли регистрация в qt корпорации ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет регистрация не обязательна. Вы видимо установили Qt через offline installer, для offline обновление через интернет не работает, чтобы обновление работало надо устанавливать Qt online installer-ом.
https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте следующий временный репозиторий в «Настройки»:

- Windows: http://download.qt.io/online/qt5/windows/x86/online_repository/
- Mac: http://download.qt.io/online/qt5/mac/x64/online_repository/

После этого вы сможете обновить компоненты Qt и увидеть новое обновление для Maintenance Tool.